# the use of to-infinitive

Tags: sentence-meaning, to-infinitive, paraphrasing, infinitive-phrases

> Colloquially, can (= ‘possibility’) is very often a proposal for future action: We can see about that tomorrow. In fact with second- and third- person subjects, can expresses a familiar though tactful imperative – the type of imperative that might be used by the captain of a sports team to the team members, or by the producer of a play to its cast: Mike and Willy, you can be standing over there; and Janet can enter from behind that curtain. It is as though the speaker does not like to exert authority openly, so, counting on co-operation from Mike and Willy, he/she merely suggests that a certain plan of action is POSSIBLE. **This is a democratic imperative, to be used in addressing a person regarded as one’s equal.**

(from <Meaning and the English Verb(3rd ed.)> by Geoffrey Leech p.74)

Here, I don't think "to be used in addressing a person regarded as one's equal" modifies "a democratic imperative" because of the existence of comma(,) between them. Then, What's the exact meaning of "This is a democratic imperative, to be used in addressing a person regarded as one’s equal."? Please paraphrasing this sentence to a complex sentence.

Comment: Whatever you've been taught about the significance of a comma in such contexts is obviously incorrect, because it's preventing you from parsing the text properly. It might help you to think of the text after the comma as ***optional, parenthetical***. Compare *This "democratic imperative construction" (used in addressing a person regarded as one’s equal) is often useful in helping to foster a "team spirit"*. Where the parenthetical could just as well be set off by commas rather than brackets. But in your example, the *second* comma isn't needed anyway, because there's no more text.

Answer (score 1):

It *does* modify 'to be used in addressing a person regarded as one's equal'. The comma provides a natural pause in the sentence, without affecting the meaning.

> This is the way you ask someone to do something without sounding like a 'superior' giving orders (e.g. a manager or an officer in the armed forces).

Answer (score 0):

> *This is a democratic imperative,* [*to be used in addressing a person*
> *regarded as one’s equal*].

You are right; the bracketed clause does not modify "democratic imperative".

The comma marks the clause as a supplement, a loosely attached expression set off by punctuation and intonation presenting supplementary, non-integrated content.

Supplements have an 'anchor' that they refer to; in this case the anchor is the NP "a democratic imperative".